# Cast each object in List[Any] to a specific type?

Tags: scala

I have a POJO object which is a wrapper around `Map[String, AnyRef]` (from Java). I want to cast the type of `AnyRef` to a specific type based on the keys of the map. The ultimate goal is to get the POJO object to return a representation of itself as a Scala Tuple, with the ultimate goal of transforming that into a Spark Row. How can I do this?

Things that don't work:

```
case class PojoToTuple(c: JavaObject) extends JavaObject(c) {

    //data: java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, AnyRef] is inherited

    val fields: Seq[Tuple2[String, Class[_]]] = Seq(("name", classOf[String]),
        ("incorporation_date", classOf[java.sql.Date]),
        ... )

    def getScalaRepresentation(): (String, Date, ...) = {
        fields.map{case (s: String, t: Class[_]) => data.get(s).asInstanceOf[t]}
    }
}

[ERROR] path\to\error: error: not found: type t
[ERROR] .map{case (s: String, t: Class[_]) => data.get(s).asInstanceOf[t]}
[ERROR]                                                                ^
```

I also tried

```
val fields: Seq[Tuple2[String, ???]] = Seq(("name", asInstanceOf[String]),
    ("incorporation_date", asInstanceOf[java.sql.Date]),
    ... )
```

but asInstanceOf is a member of abstract class `Any`, so I can't figure out how to extract it as any sort of first class object.

Any ideas?

---

The working alternative is to write

```
case class PojoToTuple(c: JavaObject) extends JavaObject(c) {

    //data: java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, AnyRef] is inherited

    val fields = Seq("name", "incorporation_date", ...)

    def getSparkRepresentation(): (String, Date, ...) = {
        (data.get("name").asInstanceOf[String],
            data.get("incorporation_date").asInstanceOf[java.sql.Date],
            ...
        )
```

I would like to get to a version where I don't have to hardcode the list of field names in twice. An additional reason I don't like this is that I want to overload the `getSparkRepresentation()` function to also accept a list of field names, to take a subset of all fields. There isn't a good way to do this with the hardcoded version.

Comment: What do you want the resulting type to be? It would be helpful if you specify what you intend to do with it after the transformation.

Comment: Short answer is you can't do that. A bit longer one is, this is an "XY problem", meaning that you don't really _need_ to do that: even if it did work, you would not have any use of it. Suppose, you do something like `val x: T = data.get(s).asInstanceOf[T]`, and it somehow works. Now you have a variable x of type `T`, about which you know absolutely nothing. How is it different from just having `Any`? What are you planning to do with this variable after casting it?

Comment: @Dima As you can see in the code, I specify the types for each object in the array. I have list of variables, I know the type for each field, but they arrive through a Java API as a Java `Map[String, Object]`. I want the ultimate result to be a Scala tuple `(String, Date, Double, ...)` in the order specified by the `fields` object.

Comment: @kingledion the point is that either you know the types at compile time (in which case you can just use them rather than dynamic classes), or they are useless to you. If you still don't see it, pretend that the cast worked, and write some code that uses the result. Show me what it is you are intending to do with it exactly that you couldn't do without cast.

Comment: @Dima I added much more detail.

Comment: @kingledion Your "working alternative" at the end seems fine to me. I don't know what you mean by "hard code the list of field names twice" - the `fields` variable is not used anywhere, you can just remove it. The problem with `getSparkRepresentation` taking a subset of all fields, is that you can't have it return different types depending on the arguments. Again, if you don't see it, try actually writing that code, pretending that you could pass the list of types in, and the cast worked. You would still need to declare the return type of the function. What would it be?